# Get workflow reports from object model

Tags: workflow, object-model, reports

I would like to call a standard workflow report (Activity Duration Report or Cancellation & Error Report) from server-side code. This is typically done by passing in the ReportId and the workflow AssociationId to the reporting.aspx page. Can I query the available reports to get the two report Guids I need?

What I really want to do is query all reports that are in the Workflow category to ensure I pick up any custom reports, but being able to access the two default reports is sufficient.